Copy data in azure data factory works with preview data but didn't when I trigger
I'm trying to copy all tables from a SQL Server to Fabric Lakehouse using the Azure Data Factory, already did with with the AWS S3 but with the SQL Server it's not working. (I know i can use the fabric, but the company prefer ingestion using ADF)
In these configurations i'm just trying copy only one table inside the lakehouse:



When I Click to see the preview data, i can see the values from database:

But when trigger the pipeline, it takes minutes/hours and the activity do nothing, even an error, so I needed to cancel:


Try to copy only the first 10 rows to see if this is a size issue. Replace on source from table to query and add the query "select top 10 * from schema.table".

@ChenHirsh still stuck the copy data, even with select top 1. I noticed the activity it's queued forever, don't change to in progress...

I noticed this is happening only with the integration run time self hosted, with azure integration works normally. But it's ok the self-hosted, I can see the preview data...

If activities only queue and do not run on SHIR, maybe SHIR is not working properly. Try to restart the service, or look at the logs.

The details are not enough.
If its a Onprem SQL Server , you would need SHIR, self hosted Intergration runtime.
